# how to remove a belongs_to field link in index

Tags: activeadmin

Active Admin by default seems to create links for fields that are belongs_to fields (in the index of the model).
I've looked everywhere in the docs to find a way to remove this, but no luck!
Any ideas on how to do this ?
Thanks Dave

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ActiveAdmin allows you to remove specific fields from its default behavior, however you can display all the fields you need on your Index page like this:

```
index do
  column :first_name
  column :last_name
  column :email
  column :gender
  #..any fields you wish to add
  default_actions
end
```

Of course you can customize the feel and look even more by using your own partials. Also, ActiveAdmin offers more docs concerning the index page here: http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages.html